# Where do I set/change my Google Chrome passphrase?

Tags: google-chrome

Every time I do a fresh install, Google Chrome asks me for my passphrase.
I have searched high and low in Google's help forum and have yet to receive or find any form of response.

When I do a fresh install, if I try to enter the passphrase (with all possible passwords I can recall) nothing works and I can't recover my extensions, bookmarks etc.

On the other hand, if I wait a bit, everything falls into place.
I close that window asking for passphrase and all my extensions, bookmarks are back.

The failure to enter a proper passphrase code gets me a message to change my passphrase in my account settings. Who knows where that is! No one at Google's forum seems to know anything about this passphrase.

Answer (score 20):

The passphrase will be your Google account password. If you've changed your Google account password *after* setting up sync & encryption, the passphrase will still be the old password.

Comment: Sathya, you are correct. I should have wrote passphrase.

Comment: Oops, didn't know "enter" makes you post. Anyway, i changed my p.w., saved it, then changed it back to same. So in theory, it should be the same as you said but it's still asking me for a passphrase. I'll try again and wait 24 hours to see what happens.

Answer (score 13):

You can reset your Google Sync passphrase at your [Google Dashboard](https://www.google.com/dashboard).

More information see the support article [Protect your synced data](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=1181035):

> If you forget your passphrase, you’ll need to reset sync via the
>   Google Dashboard. This will delete all synced data from Google’s
>   servers and disconnect all synced computers and devices, but not the
>   data that’s on your computers or devices. So your current preferences,
>   bookmarks, and passwords will remain available in the browser. You can
>   then re-enable sync with a new passphrase.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find proper answer to this questions after 45 minutes of Googling. Here is what you need:
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1181420?hl=en

Don't be afraid of clicking *STOP and CLEAR* button, it won't delete any data on your local computer. When you re-sync on Chrome, using your Gmail password as your pass phrase.

Good luck!

Comment: but it'll delete from the server, so if you doesn't have any data on your computer, it's gone forever

Comment: I assumed *sync* turned ON on client computer. Not sure if there is better way of doing it. 

Funny - After this happened, I tend NOT to use pass phrases generated by Google.

Answer (score 0):

In sync options if you just select the bookmarks and click OK
even you didn't write the passphrase it brings the bookmarks.

My old password or any other possible password was't the passphrase...
I also don't remember when I set this passphrase thing.

Comment: All I know is that it was **not** my Google Account password. I think you set it the first time you sync.

Comment: That may be a wiser thing to do but for me, my password serves the purpose just fine at this time.